# Django - Form validation not happening in modal dialog bootstrap

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

The following is the code of my forms.py

```
class Register(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=64,
                               widget=forms.TextInput({
                                   'placeholder': 'User Name'}))
    firstname = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=64,
                                widget=forms.TextInput({
                                   'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    surname = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=64,
                              widget=forms.TextInput({
                                   'placeholder': 'Sur Name / Second Name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='', max_length=64,
                              widget=forms.TextInput({
                                   'placeholder': 'Email'}))
```

While displaying the form in a simple html file the form validation is happening, whereas its not working in the modal dialog window. My html code for modal dialog window is as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ApplyJob">Apply for Job</button>
</div>
<div id="ApplyJob" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="modal-title">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ form|crispy }}

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its displaying the modal window and taking the inputs but the form validation is not happening, please help me with this. I am new to Django.

Comment: If you want to validate email field, try Emailinput instead of text input. Did u try mentioning url explicitly or mentioning url using url tag. `form action={% url 'form-submit-url'}` ?

Comment: The validation was happening perfectly in a web page, but not while using modal dialog. I will try by using the url's. The post data is sent successfully but the validation is not happening while using modal dialog. @cutteeth